# android - enter Latitude/Longitude in autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps

I have added `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` in my android app and it works perfectly when I search for a place. My question is, how do I let the user enter Latitude and Longitude values and place a marker at that coordinate? I would just like to hide "No results found" section and let user hit enter and get the coordinates.

Below is what I have so far.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
```

Code when a place is selected:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
          getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            String placeName = place.getName().toString();
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(placeName));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

[image]

I want to implement a search bar that's very much like Google Maps.

Comment: Hi what do you want to achieve ? as an example a user should be able to search a location using name or position and it should display the location.. is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a PlaceAutoCompleteFragment, use a PlaceAutocompleteIntent:

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new   
PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                                .build(getThis());
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {     
//Do something
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
//Do something                
    }
```

This will send an intent instead of directly displaying a fragment. Then, via the onResult method, you can catch the failures, and perform the reverse geocoding there:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {

        switch(requestCode){
            case RequestCodes.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE:
                switch(resultCode){
                    case RESULT_OK:
                        Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                       //Do something with the address you got.
                        break;
                    case RESULT_ERROR:
                        Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                        //In this case, if you typed coordinates instead of an address, 
                        //you can use them to perform a reverse geocoding as you want.
            break;
                    case RESULT_CANCELED:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: how get status "No results for ..." ?

Answer (score 1):

> [The Google Place API translats] a human-readable address into a
>   location on a map.

What you are trying to do is [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding).

Android has a [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) you can use for this purpose. You would have to implement your own fragment to do this, but it will not work using the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to let the user search for places by the place name or address which is why I used `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`. Is there a way to use the search bar as a regular `editText` and just get the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

@parth-bhoiwala Please follow below link for your solution.
**https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget**
In that link scroll down to go to "Get place predictions programmatically" section

You can create a custom search UI as an alternative to the UI provided by the autocomplete widget. To do this, your app must get place predictions programmatically. Your app can get a list of predicted place names and/or addresses from the autocomplete service by calling GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()

Comment: keep in mind, if you do this, you'll be affected by the quota limits, while using the Google UI (fragment or intent) will not.